# print stylesheet not fully working

Tags: css, printing

I have a webpage with a print button here: http://vitaminjdesign.com/IAM/plant-care-info/sod-care/

When you press the print button, it will print the page perfectly, BUT without any bullet points.

My CSS for list items is as follows:

```
ul li{ background:url(images/bullet.png) no-repeat 0 3px; list-style:none;}
ol li{background:none; list-style:decimal;}
```

I am confused as to why the printout doesn't include any of the list item's styling (no bullets, numbers, or background images.) Any easy fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the browser drops any background images when printing. (You can usually change that behaviour in the print dialog.)

I think the only way to safely get around that is using `list-style-image` or an explicit `img`.